# Regex to be able filter contact name spoofing

Tags: regex, email

My company has been targeted by some phishers that are spoofing our CEOs contact name in the from header however, because we have SPF and DKIM, they are unable to spoof his actual email address otherwise it would get blocked.  So the FROM header they are sending is:

John Doe

I'd like to be able to filter emails that contain the name John Doe but that do not contain my CEO's actual email address, johndoe@mycompany.com.  Is this possible with regex?

In response to a comment, I am not looking for any output, just whether a match was found so that it can be used to determine if the email should be filtered or not.  Some examples:

```
John Doe <johndoe@mycompany.com>           <-- do not match this
John Doe <spoofer@validemailaddress.com>   <-- match this
John Doe <asdf@aasdf.com>                  <-- match this
```

I did not realize this until I tried to use the answer provided by visualnotsobasic it but the regex needs to be in the RE2 specification.  I did a quick search and it seems that RE2 does not have a negative look ahead so I am hoping there is a some kind of workaround...

Comment: post your input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you.

```
((John Doe\s?)(<john.?doe|<\w+)@(?!(mycompany.com)).*>)
```

This allows for email addresses with a potential symbol between first and last name, e.g. john_doe@whatevermail.com, etc.

It will exclude your boss's real email address.
You can test here:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: This seems to be close, but the name 'John Doe' must precede the email address.

Comment: That was working however I just realized that this needs to use the RE2 syntax... any chance you could update your answer to use that?

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is match what you don't want and capture in a group what you want to keep using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

The valid email is in the first [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

That will match:

```
John Doe <johndoe@mycompany\.com>|(John Doe <\S+@\S+>)
```

- `John Doe <johndoe@mycompany\.com>` Match
- `|` Or
- `(John Doe <\S+\S+>)` Capture in the first capture group John Doe followed by an e-mail like pattern matching 1+ non-whitespace characters `\S+` and @ and again 1+ non-whitespace characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SXOsAi/1)